# How to add a DNS record in GCP using Terraform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dns, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I'm trying to get terraform to add an "A" record to my dns zone in GCP. Efforts to do so result in an error: "update server is not set". A similar error is described [here](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-dns/issues/83). So I gather from comments made there that I need an update item in my dns provider. Which I dutifully tried to provide.

```
provider "dns" {
  update {
    server = "xxx.xxx.x.x"
  }
}
```

Except that I have no idea what IP goes in there, and my first attempts have failed.

Will I need other settings?

I note [in the documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/dns/index.html) the following format...

```
provider "dns" {
  update {
    server        = "192.168.0.1"
    key_name      = "example.com."
    key_algorithm = "hmac-md5"
    key_secret    = "3VwZXJzZWNyZXQ="
  }
}
```

I don't understand where these settings come from.

**Update:**
Martin's advice (accepted answer below) worked like a charm.

For the next person struggling with this, the trick was to use `google_dns_record_set` instead of `dns_a_record_set`.

Comment: Always funny to find yourself a year later reading a strangely familiar SO question. Only to realize it was you who posted it. Thank you, @Martin, again. I'm here because I got bit by this same problem. Again. This time around with dns_ns_record_set. Solution was the same. google_dns_record_set.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `dns` provider is implementing the standard DNS update protocol defined in [RFC 2136: Dynamic Updates in the Domain Name System](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2136), which tends to be implemented by self-hosted DNS server software like [BIND](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIND). In that case, the credentials would be configured on the server side by the BIND operator and then you'd in turn pass the given credentials into the provider.

Unfortunately, as DNS has tended towards being a managed service provided for you by various vendors, most of these vendors have chosen to ignore RFC 2136 and implement their own proprietary APIs instead. For that reason, the management capabilities of Terraform's `dns` provider are incompatible with most managed DNS products.

Instead, we manage these using a vendor-specific provider. In your case, since you are apparently using Google Cloud DNS, you'd manage your DNS zones and records using resource types from the `google` Terraform provider. Specifically:

- [`google_dns_managed_zone`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/dns_managed_zone.html) for the zone itself
- [`google_dns_record_set`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/dns_record_set.html) for recordsets within the zone

Here is a minimal example to get started:

```
resource "google_dns_managed_zone" "example" {
  name     = "example"
  dns_name = "example.com."
}

resource "google_dns_record_set" "example" {
  managed_zone = google_dns_managed_zone.example.name

  name    = "www.${google_dns_managed_zone.example.dns_name}"
  type    = "A"
  rrdatas = ["10.1.2.1", "10.1.2.2"]
  ttl     = 300
}
```

A key advantage of these vendors using vendor-specific APIs is that the management operations integrate with the authentication mechanisms used for the rest of their APIs, and so as long as your Google Cloud Platform provider has credentials with sufficient privileges to manage these objects you shouldn't need any additional provider configuration for this.

Terraform has provider support for a number of different managed DNS vendors, so folks not using Google Cloud DNS will hopefully find that their chosen vendor is also supported in a similar way, by browsing [the available providers](https://registry.terraform.io/browse/providers).

Comment: Martin, your answer was nothing short of perfect. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Martin What should done if our chosen vendor is not in that list? We use easydns actually. Could you please have a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64853533/how-to-automate-adding-a-dns-entry-in-easydns-with-terraform

Comment: If there is no provider available for the vendor you want to use then unfortunately I think your options are non-ideal: you could ask the vendor to develop a Terraform provider, you could develop a Terraform provider yourself, you could manage using something other than Terraform, or you could select another DNS vendor.