# How to automate adding a dns entry in easydns with terraform?

Tags: oracle, ubuntu, ansible, dns, terraform

I am automating creating a instance in oracle cloud and deploy some apps in it.

After setting up the instance, I want to add a dns entry that maps the public IP of the new instance to a FQDN in easydns.com. And also want to generate Let's Encrypt TLS certificates for that FQDN using certbot in the instance. Currently, I'm doing this manually.

I want to automate this second part using Terraform or ansible.

- I found a **EasyDNS DNS Challenge Provider** here in terraform, but i think this is for dns challenge, and i'm still confused how to use it to add the dns entry.:
  https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/acme/dns_providers/easydns.html
- Can i use this **DNS Provider** to add an A record in easydns? ( Don't now if easydns supports RFC 2136 ) :
  https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/dns/latest/docs
- Is there any Ansible module something like below using which i can achieve the same?
  https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/nsupdate_module.html
  https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/dnsimple_module.html
- Or is it a good option to add OCI DNS as secondary dns or something like that?

Can someone help me in this?

Answer (score 1):

You are right. The linked provider is not for creating DNS entries.

You need to find (implement?) a Terraform provider for EasyDNS DNS entries. I cannot see one in either of the lists:

- https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/index.html
- https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/type/community-index.html

Maybe there's some low-profile open-source project. Or you can ask the vendor if they have any Terraform provider or plans to add it.

Comment: Can i use this DNS Provider to add an A record in easydns: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/dns/latest/docs ? But don't know if easydns supports RFC 2136 !

Comment: Interesting. I wasn't aware of this. 
If EasyDNS supports that - good question.